# Erro ao apagar dados no Mysql pelo Java

Tags: java, mysql, junit, chave-estrangeira

No banco de dados eu tenhos três tabelas, onde uma delas guarda as chaves estrangeiras.
Erro apresentado:
Erro: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_teste`.`tbl_Relacao`, CONSTRAINT `tbl_Relacao_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`primeira_pessoa`) REFERENCES `pessoas` (`id_pessoas`))

Classe parentes:

```
public class Parentes {
private int id_parentes;
private int nivel;
private String parentesco;
//getters e setters
```

Classe pessoa:

```
public class Pessoa {
private int id_pessoa;
private String sexo;
private String nome;
private String usuario;
private String senha;
//getters e setters
```

Classe relacao:

```
public class Relacao {
private int id_relacao;
private int primeira_pessoa;
private int segunda_pessoa;
private int tipo_relacao;
private Parentes parente;
private Pessoa pessoa1;
private Pessoa pessoa2;
//getters e setters
```

Delete de parentesDAO:

```
public boolean delete(Parentes parentes){
    String sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_parentes WHERE id_parentes = ?";
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;

    try {
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setInt(1, parentes.getId_parentes());
        stmt.executeUpdate();

        return true;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: "+ex);
        return false;
    }
    finally{
        ConnectionFactory.closeConnection(con, (com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement) stmt);
    }
}
```

Delete de pessoaDAO:

```
    public boolean update(Pessoa pessoa){
    String sql = "UPDATE pessoas SET nome = ?, sexo = ? WHERE id_pessoas = ?";

    PreparedStatement stmt = null;

    try {
        stmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setString(1, pessoa.getNome());
        stmt.setString(2, pessoa.getSexo());
        stmt.setInt(3, pessoa.getId_pessoa());
        stmt.executeUpdate();

        return true;

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("Erro: " + ex);
        return false;
    }finally{
        ConnectionFactory.closeConnection(con, stmt);
    }
}
```

Delete de relacaoDAO:

```
    public boolean delete(Relacao relacao){
    String sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_Relacao WHERE id_relacao = ?";
    java.sql.PreparedStatement stmt = null;

    try {
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setInt(1, relacao.getId_relacao());
        stmt.executeUpdate();

        return true;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: "+ex);
        return false;
    }
    finally{
        ConnectionFactory.closeConnection(con, (com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement) stmt);
    }
}
```

Estou usando JUnit para fazer o teste, segue abaixo o código:

```
   public void deleteDAO() {
    Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
    PessoaDAO pessoaDAO = new PessoaDAO();

    Relacao relacionamento = new Relacao();
    RelacaoDAO relacionamentoDAO = new RelacaoDAO();

    Parentes parentes = new Parentes();
    ParentesDAO parentesDAO = new ParentesDAO();

    //pessoa.setId_pessoa(3);

    //Qualquer valor vai apresentar o mesmo erro
    pessoa.setId_pessoa(c.getId_pessoa());

    parentes.setId_parentes(c.getId_parentes());

    relacionamento.setId_relacao(c.getId_relacao());


    if(pessoaDAO.delete(pessoa) && relacionamentoDAO.delete(relacionamento) && parentesDAO.delete(parentes)){
        System.out.println("Removido com sucesso!");
    }
    else{
        fail("Erro ao deletar");
    }
}
```

O problema é que quando eu tento apagar os dados aparece um erro na tabela que contém as chaves estrangeiras, eu gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo de errado.

Obs: sou iniciante.

Comment: Primeiro tente remover somente a pessoaDAO e vê se o erro apresenta, pelo que me parece você está tentando remover um registro que possui referência em outra tabela.Como Relacao tem referência de pessoa e parentes o certo seria remover primeiro a relacao depois a pessoa e parentes. A tabela Relacao não pode ter registros órfãos.

Comment: Vai no phpmyadmin ou em outro gerenciador de banco que vc esteja usando, procura "tbl_Relacao" e procura a constant "tbl_Relacao_ibfk_1" e coloquei a integridade para CASCATA, para que quando um delete ou update seja realizado o banco distribua a cascata nos relacionamentos

Answer (score 1):

Como você está iniciando, vamos por partes como diria o jack...

**1. Não coloque nome de entidade no plural:**

Ex: Parentes >> Parente

**2. Não coloque nome de atributo no java com underline (_):**

Ex: id_pessoa >> idPessoa

**3. Erro de constraint ao tentar excluir**

Tente alterar a ordem de exclusão para:

> ```
> if(relacionamentoDAO.delete(relacionamento) && pessoaDAO.delete(pessoa) && parentesDAO.delete(parentes)){
>     System.out.println("Removido com sucesso!");
> }
> ```

Outra solução seria trabalhar com o cascade no banco.

**Dúvida:** A tabela Parentes se relaciona com qual tabela? Na sua classe isto não está claro.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas dicas karanalpe, a tabela parentes está se relacionando com a tabela relacionamento.

Comment: Funcionou alterar a ordem de exclusão?

Comment: Funcionou, porém antes disso estava apresentando o seguinte erro:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed. para efeito de teste eu apaguei todas os seguintes pontos:                                          finally{
           ConnectionFactory.closeConnection(con, (com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement) stmt);
        } E o código funcionou normalmente, mas agora a minha dúvida é a seguinte, estou fazendo certo em apagar?

Comment: Certo e errado é relativo. Uma opção mais fácil seria trabalhar com cascade do banco.

Comment: Blz Karanalpe, valeu pelas dicas.